# Recreating old Wordpress pages as HTML by passing variables

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm moving from Wordpress to a static site which shall have .htm files for pages.

The thing is I have a couple of old pages that had this basic format here:

"http://www.domain.com/?p=1295"

I need the URL to remain exactly the same as above even though the remaining pages will be .htm files.

Is there an easy way to do that? There are not many pages. 7 pages or so, so I could definitely recreate links mnanually.

I just want to create a simple script that will do as follows:

Say for example my old link is http://www.domain.com/?p=1295: the script will check if there is a variable for "p" 1295 (which will contain my html) and if not, just load the site "http://www.domain.com" as usual.

Probably is something like "get this, else move on", but as you can see I'm helpless with coding :D

Thanks in advance!

PS: I have searched the forum and I was trying to accomplish something with $_GET and all, but I'm not very good with coding as this is not really my area. So I just wanted something simple to recreate those pages without much headache.

Thanks again!

Comment: Your better off using a `301 redirect`

Comment: I know that a 301 would be an easy solution, but I'd like to keep the old link exactly as it is as these pages have Pagerank and even though a 301 would pass the 'link juice', I'm better off by recreating these pages exactly as they are as this means that the PR will be guaranteed (as it already exists).

By doing a 301 redirect, yes, the user will be taken to the same page, but the PR that page got over time might not go through.

Answer (score 0):

Using a 301 redirect in your `.htaccess` would probably work just fine.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=13$
RewriteRule ^/page.php$ http://www.example.com/newname.htm? [L,R=301]
```